# Algebra (check if a structure is a ring with identity).

Tags: abstract-algebra

Help me to check if this set is ring with identity
$${f ∈ C[a,b] : f(a) = f(b)}$$

First i need to check if it is a abelian group and then ring condition with condition for indentity. How to start with checking if it is group.
I'm confused with this $f(a)=f(b)$, if it is just $ C[a,b]$ then there is no problem to check it.

Comment: $f(a) + g(a) = f(b) + g(b)$, $-f(a) = -f(b)$.

Comment: *and for ring condition $a(b+c)=ab+ac$ it schould be like this:
$f(a)(g(a)+h(a))=f(a)g(a) + f(a)h(a) 
since 
f(a)=f(b) ?$*

Comment: *I need more details to make this really good. Can you help ?*

Answer (score 1):

If you accept that $C[a,b]$ is a ring (and it sounds like you do), then you can apply the fact that a subset of a ring is a subring if and only if it contains the identity and is closed under addition and multiplication.

Comment: *Can i get this written out really good ? 
I have some idea how to write it but, there are no examples so i do  not know if i'm correct. 
I'm not sure here : for ring condition $a(b+c)=ab+ac$ it schould be like this: $f(a)(g(a)+h(a))=f(a)g(a)+f(a)h(a) since f(a)=f(b)?$*